# Lucene librairy for purify a text (plurial, verbs...)

Tags: java, lucene, purify

I would like some help to use Lucene in my Java App to simplify a text.

I already did it myself but I don't have solution for verbs and plurial.

How can I process ?

Comment: Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
How about trying smth and share a piece of code?

Comment: Its somewhat clear what you're asking. But please go and read the link that provided by the above comment. We aren't help you to **write code** but we can help you to **solve specific problem**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to detect nouns/verb from a text. AFAIK Lucene on its own does not have capability to detect this. You can instead look at [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) library which is a

> machine learning based toolkit for the processing of natural language
>   text

So it would be using concepts like training models and then predicting. It has a POSTagger API (part of speech tagger) - you can take a look at it's usage [here](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/manual/opennlp.html#tools.postagger.tagging.cmdline) in docs and some detailed examples  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603865/java-opennlp-extract-all-nouns-from-a-sentence),[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opennlp/opennlp_finding_parts_of_speech.htm) and [here](https://gist.github.com/johnmiedema/e12e7359bcb17b03b8a0).

Another excellent framework in Java is [Stanford Core NLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) You can take a look at *Stanford Log-linear Part-Of-Speech Tagger* [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml)